# How to get Telegram channels updates (posts) with api?

Tags: api, telegram, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I want  to get Telegram channels updates (posts) with api by php! (I am not channels admin)

I am not sure can I do this with bot or not?

if it is not possible how can do that with telegram api ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, If your bot is an administrator of the channel you can listen for [channel_post](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) updates.

If it is not an administrator, you will have to use the Telegram Core API. See [this library](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto).

Comment: I am not channels admin

Comment: @soheilyo See edit above

Comment: tnx , do you have any sample php code ?

Comment: https://github.com/hbashton/BruhhBot-Madeline/blob/5de0788866053b27e7b5a570d914bdfa80a01020/check_msg.php